# Backbone.js : No Network scenario - options.error not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a page developed using backbone, handlebar and _.js. While fetching the model (as a normal http jsonp callback request), i do set options.error and options.success. The success callback gets called properly. However, to simulate the network down scenario, when i disable the network adapter in my PC (from control panel) and trigger the call again, the error callback is not getting called.

Could anyone please suggest if I am doing anything wrong?

Thanks and Best Regards,
V. Vasanth

Answer (score 0):

Need look at the code to find out what's the problem. If you put callbacks to fetch method that should be right:

```
model.fetch({
    success:function()
    {
    },
    error:function()
    {
    }
});
```

If you override model sync method it could be like this:

```
sync:function(method, model, options)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"your_url",
        // some other configs
        success:function(data)
        {
            options.success(data);
        }
        error:function()
        {
            options.error();
        }

    })
}
```